# Regex to grab a bit rate value from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am using FFMPEG in the command line to get the media info on my files in an ASP.NET C# application. I need to grab the bit rate value from the string value which contains the FFMPEG output like so:

```
  Duration: 00:00:02.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 517 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1024x768, 15.00 tb(r)
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 22050 Hz, mono, s16
```

So I want to get out the integer value from `bitrate: 517 kb/s` using Regex... The bit rate of my files in context only got up to around the 1500 mark, so it would need to be able to get 2, 3, and 4 digit values.

How can this be achieved?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(ffmpegStr, @"bitrate: (\d+)");

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Where `ffmpegStr` is your data.

You can replace the `+` with `{2,4}` to only match 2 to 4 digits.

---

Alternatively you can use [ffprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) to output machine read-friendly data.

Comment: Why the double backslash in your example?

Comment: My mistake, I was under the impression C# required double backslash in regex.

Comment: FFprobe can output in JSON, this can easily be parsed and then the regex can be run against the bit rate

Answer (score 1):

You can get as many digits as the string has using `+` qualifier:

```
bitrate: (?<bitrate>\d+) kb/s
```

Read the value from the `"bitrate"` capture group.

Answer (score 0):

```
(bitrate:\s)(\d+)
```

Above will match and create 2 groups. The integer value will be in the second group.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex....

```
string line = "Duration: 00:00:02.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 517 kb/s";
string pattern = "bitrate: ";
int bitrate = -1;
int index = line.IndexOf(pattern, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if(index >= 0)
{
    index += pattern.Length;
    int endIndex = line.IndexOf(" kb/s", index + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if(endIndex >= 0)
    {
        int.TryParse(line.Substring(index, endIndex - index), out bitrate);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/FE1cQP

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're parsing FFmpeg output.  FFmpeg allows output to JSON (and some other formats) that make it easier to grab whatever data you need.  You may want to investigate that option instead of relying on a regex.